# The "moderator tools" privilege page still lists 2000 rep as the threshold

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools

The number on the right is okay, but the text itself reads:

> When you achieve **2000** reputation, you will earn...

Should be 10,000 - or, better yet, it should be identical to how it looks in other SE-2.0 sites (here's the same page on [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools)).

Comment: Ahahaha, wow, that really came back to bite me, didn't it? I think I am probably at fault for that. Prior to them crafting the wikis on Meta, I wrote that one quickly by copying what was originally on Meta and replacing 10k with 2k. If you check out the [current privilege list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), you'll see that the entry is drastically different. It seems they didn't copy over that specific page due to my earlier edit. Whoops...

Comment: @Grace So is there no way to fix it then?

Comment: @Strix Currently, not by us diamonds. This is a live bug and ideally the devs will get around to repairing it at some point. Until then, we'll just have to settle with a certain individual's horrific mistake... again...

Comment: You should post this on MSO to get the page pushed back out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed this, but will take a few more hours to take effect